# setting NODE_ENV for node.js + expressjs application as a daemon under ubuntu

Tags: linux, node.js, daemon, express

i got the daemon working alright with these instructions:
http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/run_nodejs_as_a_service_on_ubuntu_karmic/

but because this starts the application in DEVELOPMENT mode, the log file gets spammed with socket.io debug logs.

i tried setting the NODE_ENV to production in the upstart-conf-file but had no success.

```
script
    export HOME="/root"
    export NODE_ENV=production

    exec /usr/local/bin/node /where/yourprogram.js >> /var/log/node.log 2>&1
end script
```

didn't work.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try

```
exec NODE_ENV=production /usr/local/bin/node /where/yourprogram.js >> /var/log/node.log 2>&1
```

In my setup I'm sudoing as a lesser user, so it's

```
exec sudo -u some-user NODE_ENV=production /usr/local/bin/node /where/yourprogram.js >> /var/log/node.log 2>&1
```

and since it's spawning off another user it probably has another environment. I'm a newbie here, but it works for me.

Comment: The first option does not work and throws the following error: `/proc/self/fd/9: 3: exec: NODE_ENV=production: not found`

Comment: That might be because I'm relying on bash syntax. Check which shell you are using and correct the command accordingly.

Comment: This is what worked for me in the end

`script
    export NODE_ENV=production
    exec /usr/bin/node /someapp/server.js >> /var/log/someapp.log 2>&1
end script`

Answer (score 18):

Here's a simpler upstart script you can use. Upstart now supports everything you need to do directly without script sections or too much embedded shell syntax. This includes environment variables (`env`), working directory (`chdir`), user/group (`setuid`, `setgid`), log handling (`console log`), etc. Your log files will be handled and rotated into `/var/log/upstart/your_app.log`

```
description "start and stop the example express.js/node.js server"
author "John Doe <jd@example.com>"

start on filesystem and started networking
respawn
console log
chdir /opt/your_app
setuid your_app_user
setgid your_app_user
env PATH=./node_modules/.bin:./node/bin:/usr/bin
env NODE_ENV=production
exec app/server.js
```

Answer (score 15):

If you are using node.js in production, I recommend you use forever.js to daemonize your program
https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever

Install using npm:  `[sudo] npm install forever -g`

`export NODE_ENV=production` and run `forever start app.js` You can also specify where to put error and stdout logs.

Comment: For something more advanced, you can also check out: https://github.com/learnboost/cluster

Comment: Just to clarify on @TiansHUo last comment, Cluster doesn't solve the "keep it running" problem like Upstart with Respawn, Upstart + Monit, or Forever.

Comment: IMHO Upstart is better approach under Ubuntu than forever

Comment: Notice if, for any reason, you have to launch forever command as sudo, you have to set the NODE_ENV environment variable in the same line: sudo NODE_ENV=production forever start app.js

Answer (score 4):

to set NODE_ENV in heroku use:

```
heroku config:set NODE_ENV="production"
```

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu/Upstart are listed in the question, but I got here while looking for answers for a FreeBSD/system shell daemon.

The line below started the app in "development" environment:

```
exec node path/to/start/script.js
```

The line below started the app in "production" environment:

```
NODE_ENV=production exec node path/to/start/script.js
```

It took me a while to figure this out, so I thought I'd share.