# Setting up process.env variables using EXPORT while running node with sudo

Tags: node.js, sudo

I'm using node.js on EC2

I type

```
EXPORT PORT=80
```

in terminal, and i see that it correctly saves it when i type EXPORT

But when I run my node.js app with the following:

```
...
console.log(process.env);
...
```

PORT is not listed in the object when I'm running it with sudo:

```
sudo node app.js
```

How do I set PORT so that I can access it from the process.env object while running node with sudo?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To set `process.env` variable use the following code:

```
sudo PORT=80 node server.js
```

Of course, you can set multiple `process.env` variables:

```
sudo PORT=80 HOST=localhost node server.js
```

Normally, `EXPORT` should work too. But `sudo` creates its own environments and then starts your program as `root`. So, you shall either add `PORT` to `sudo`'s environment or force it to preserve your own environment.

To change `sudo`'s environment you shall modify `/root/.profile`.

To force it to preserve your own environment use `-E` key:

```
sudo -E node app.js
```

Comment: Is there no way to set it up permanently so I don't have to set them up every time I run the server?

Comment: `EXPORT` should work too. It works for me, though I prefer not to change the global environment.

Comment: If you want to configure your environment for production then its better to write [simple upstart script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7028694/1202461).

Comment: Yes, I've been using both a forever script and setting it up every time I run node.  But I want to change the global env to include PORT.  `EXPORT` **should** work, but it's not for me.  I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: If `export PORT=8080 && node -e "console.log(process.env.PORT);"` prints `undefined` for you, then I have no idea why its happening. If it prints `8080`, then include more details about the way you starting your script and I'll try to help you.

Comment: Ah. I think I identified the problem, but don't know how to solve it.  I got `PORT=8080` working.  But I'm actually trying to get it to work on `PORT=80`.  So I need to do `export PORT=80`, `sudo node app.js`, which causes `process.env.PORT` to be `undefined`.  Any advice on how to get PORT 80 to work?

Comment: Are you sure that no other applications are already listening to port 80? If you have `ngnix` or `appach` installed then port 80 may be already taken. Are you sure that your problem is with setting `process.env.PORT` and not with listening to port 80?

Comment: The thing is, when I do `sudo PORT=80 node app.js`, it runs perfectly on PORT 80.  Only when I do `export PORT=80` and then run `sudo node app.js` separately is where the problem occurs.  Maybe it's some sort of permissions issue?

Comment: Ok, now I figured out your problem. `Sudo` creates its own environments and then starts you program as `root`. So, you shall either add `PORT` to `sudo`'s environment or force it to preserve your own environment. To change `sudo`'s environment you shall modify `/root/.profile`. To force it to preserve your own environment use `-E` key (e.g. `sudo -E node app.js`).

Comment: I edited your question and my answer to reflect the real problem and appropriate solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old post but I have the same permission problem running node.js on port 80. I made a workaround to avoid running with `sudo` and having to define the PORT in node run command (`sudo PORT=80 node server.js`). What I did was redirect the traffic for the PORT 80 to another allowed port, in my case 3000.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env#usage) to set up env and add to your scripts.
eg.

```
scripts: {
"build": "cross-env PORT=3000 <any_command>"
}
```

You can also set multiple variables .
eg.

```
scripts: {
    "build": "cross-env PORT=3000 NODE_ENV=production <any_command>"
    }
```

Process this using process.env.PORT and process.env.NODE_ENV